# Why does tone change when I change the block size?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

```
import pyaudio

import numpy as np

RATE=44100
block = 64
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = pa.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                            channels=1,
                            rate=RATE,
                            output=True)

while True:
    x = np.arange(block,dtype=np.float32)
    output = np.cos(2*np.pi*2000*x/44100)
    output = output.tobytes()
    stream.write(output)
```

I want to play a cosine wave with 2000Hz frequency and 64 block size. Why does tone change when I change the block size? It should be fixed tone with certain frequency whatever the block size is, shouldn't it?
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Peter Schneider Could you give me some advice, please? Thank you.

Comment: Does it sound like a sine tone? You should try to plot a few blocks next to each other, then you should see what's the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with your calculation. For a 2kHz-sound, you need 2000 sin-waves every second or every 44100 samples/ 1 sin-wave every ~22 samples or 0.5ms. The best way to find such formulas is grabbing pen and paper and find out what you actually want (how to actually combine frequency, sampling-rate and desired blocklength). One possible way is here but try to understand the math behind (untested):

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

RATE=44100
FREQUENCY = 2000

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = pa.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
             channels=1,
             rate=RATE,
             output=True)

sample_len = 4000.0        
wave_len = float(RATE) / FREQUENCY # ~22 samples per wave
# x goes from 0 to 1 for approx index 0..wave_len-1, 1..2 for wave_len..2wave_len-1, ...
x = np.arange(sample_len,dtype=np.float32)/wave_len
# 0..1 -> 0..1..0..-1..0; 1..2 -> 0..1..0..-1..0
# yes, I prefer sin over cos
output = np.sin(2*np.pi*x) 
output = output.tobytes()

# no need to recreate the pattern every cycle            
while True:
    stream.write(output)
```

Comment: I think your computation is same as mine. Is `sample_len` the block size? When I run the program, the different block size will cause different tones played. But, it should not be like that.

Comment: This is basically the same code as OP has provided, just less readable.